# Concatenate quotes with a string in a loop in R

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I want to concatenate quotes with a string in a loop. I tried to use the below code, but this only generates a warning:

> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet.\"") : invalid factor level, NA generated.

What is wrong here?

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
        if(i < length(x)){
            print(paste("\"", items[i,], "\"", sep = ""))
        } else { print(items[i,]) }
}
```

Comment: What you think is a string is actually a factor. You have to convert it to a string first before you you use paste. You should provide what the objects "items" and "x" are.

Comment: To further @CactusWoman's comment: (1) try `items[i,] = paste("\"", as.character(items[i,]), "\"", sep = "")`; (2) otherwise, we cannot help you without a better idea of what your data looks like.

Comment: You should provide a few lines of items and x, try showing us the results of head (items) and head(x)

Comment: Better yet, show us `dput(head(items))` and `dput(x)`.

Comment: if you run `items<-as.character(items)` before your loop it should work fine, you can't add new elements to a column of type factor if they are not already in the levels, so you have to transform `items` to characters before reassigning its elements.

Comment: @NicE's comment works as long as (a) `items` is a single column matrix/data.frame, or (b) you want to convert all columns. I was typing as you commented that ... :-)

Comment: @NicE Thanks! This solved my problem: `items[,1] <- as.character(items[,1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your column is a `factor`:

```
items <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L),
                            .Label = c("Am f?cut multe din lucrurile pe care mi le-am dorit.", 
                                "Am sentimente calde fa?? de ceilal?i.", "Nu sunt interesat de al?i oameni. (I) ", 
                                "Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)", "Rareori m? trezesc odihnit. (I)", 
                                "Sunt pesimist în leg?tur? cu viitorul. (I)"),
                            class = "factor")),
                   .Names = "V1",
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                   class = "data.frame")
x <- structure(list(SSB1 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L),
                    SSB2 = c(5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L),
                    SSB3 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L),
                    SSB4 = c(6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L),
                    SSB5 = c(5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L),
                    SSB6 = c(6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L),
                    SSB7 = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L),
                    SSB8 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L),
                    SSB9 = c(6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L),
                    SSB10 = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L)),
               .Names = c("SSB1", "SSB2", "SSB3", "SSB4", "SSB5",
                   "SSB6", "SSB7", "SSB8", "SSB9", "SSB10"),
               class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

class(items[,1])
## [1] "factor"
paste("\"", items[1,], "\"", sep = "")
## [1] "\"Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)\""
```

The simple `paste` function works fine, but when you try to assign it back to the same row (you should be more explicit, btw, by using `item[i,1]` instead of just `item[i,]`, especially if you are intending to collapse strings):

```
items[1,] <- paste("\"", items[1,], "\"", sep = "")
## Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "\"Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)\"") :
##   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

***NB***: *we will need to reload items since we just corrupted the first row.*

The problem is that the string resulting from the `paste` command is not recognized as one of the levels of the factor.

```
levels(items[,1])
## [1] "Am f?cut multe din lucrurile pe care mi le-am dorit."
## [2] "Am sentimente calde fa?? de ceilal?i."               
## [3] "Nu sunt interesat de al?i oameni. (I) "              
## [4] "Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)"         
## [5] "Rareori m? trezesc odihnit. (I)"                     
## [6] "Sunt pesimist în leg?tur? cu viitorul. (I)"          

paste("\"", items[1,], "\"", sep = "")
## [1] "\"Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)\""
```

In order to assign an arbitrary string into this `factor`-ized column, you must either (a) ensure the string you are assigning is the same as one of the defined levels, (b) add levels to the column to account for your new string (probably not efficient nor what you are wanting to do), or (c) just convert the whole column to `character` before you even begin this. The first two are inefficient and (IMO) unnecessary, but let me know if I'm misinterpreting your needs.

For (c):

```
items[,1] <- as.character(items[,1])
items[1,] <- paste("\"", items[1,], "\"", sep = "")
items
##                                                     V1
## 1        "Nu sunt mul?umit de felul în care sunt. (I)"
## 2               Nu sunt interesat de al?i oameni. (I) 
## 3 Am f?cut multe din lucrurile pe care mi le-am dorit.
## 4                Am sentimente calde fa?? de ceilal?i.
## 5                      Rareori m? trezesc odihnit. (I)
## 6           Sunt pesimist în leg?tur? cu viitorul. (I)
```

### TL;DR;

You have to convert (your column) to a string first before you use paste.

Comment: I left the second line as it was initialy: `items[i,] = paste("\"", items[i,], "\"", sep = "")`. I only added the `items[,1] <- as.character(items[,1])` before the loop (in my original code). Thanks again! Now my code works!